# env variables from compose to client-side nextjs

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have services in compose:

```yaml
services:
  exchange-frontend:
    container_name: exchange-frontend
    ports:
      - '3010:3000'
    environment:
      NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL: exchange-backend
    networks:
      - proxy-network
  
  exchange-backend:
    container_name: exchange-backend
    ports:
      - '3011:3001'
    networks:
      - database-network
      - proxy-network
  
  database:
    networks:
      - database-network
```

In `printenv` in exchange-frontend container I got: `NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL: exchange-backend`
But in requests from axios I got `localhost:3010/undefined/uploads`

In code I use: `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL`

What I try:

```yaml
environment:
  NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL: exchange-backend
  NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL: exchange-backend:3011
  NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL: exchange-backend:3001
```

Wrote in .env file in frontend directory, but it dont converts to ip or smthng, just was: `exchange-backend` or `http://exchange-backend`